# Citeproc error after updating to debian buster - void variable bibtex completion display formats

Tags: emacs, org-mode, bibtex, citations

I am able to insert article citations in org mode using org-cite-insert but when i try to export it to html i get the following error. It worked beautifully a day ago but is acting up after i basically powerwashed my chromebook to install debian buster. Would really appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable bibtex-completion-display-formats)
  byte-code("\306 \210\307\10\310\11!\n#\210\311\303\312\313\314DD\315\316\317\320\321&\7\210\322\13G\13\323\3\3X\203G\0\1:\203G\0\1@\262\1\324\1@\f..." [org-mode-map org-ref-insert-cite-key org-ref-insert-link-function org-ref-bibtex-completion-actions helm-source-bibtex bibtex-completion-format-citation-functions org-ref-bibtex-completion-completion define-key kbd custom-declare-variable funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe914>) "Cons cells of string and function to set the actio..." :type (alist :key-type (string) :value-type (function)) :group org-ref 0 nil helm-delete-action-from-source helm-add-action-to-source org-ref-bibtex-completion-format-org #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f4010b9da114>) "Function for how `helm-bibtex' inserts citations." org-mode org-ref-helm-insert-cite-link org-ref-cite-click-helm org-ref-bibtex-completion-add-keywords-field #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400016fe5d4>) "Whether to add the `keywords' field to bibtex-comp..." boolean keywords "keywords" alist-get t "{keywords:" string-match " ${keywords:31}" org-ref-insert-cite-function org-ref-cite-onclick-function bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields bibtex-completion-display-formats inhibit-changing-match-data] 8)
  require(org-ref-helm-bibtex)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-422164> nil "/home/pixel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-2.0.0/org-r..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1644
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/pixel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-2.0.0/org-r..." "/home/pixel/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ref-2.0.0/org-r..." nil t)
  require(org-ref)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/pixel/.emacs.d/elpa/citeproc-org-0.2.4/..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1539
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/pixel/.emacs.d/elpa/citeproc-org-0.2.4/..." "/home/arcotpixel/.emacs.d/elpa/citeproc-org-0.2.4/..." nil t)
  citeproc-org-render-references(html)
  run-hook-with-args(citeproc-org-render-references html)
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil (:output-file "article.html"))
  org-export-to-file(html "article.html" nil nil nil nil nil)
  org-html-export-to-html(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Comment: The error says `bibtex-completion-display-formats` is void. Are you missing a package or configuration?

Comment: Yes. I was missing an org-ref portion. 
(setq bibtex-completion-display-formats
'((t . "${author:36} ${title:*} ${year:4} ${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${=type=:7}")))